# Are there any clues about why Jefferson has killed his wife?

Tags: inside-man-tv

In the Netflix miniseries [*Inside Man*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10948716/), one of the main characters is a prisoner on death row, who has killed his wife. But the exact circumstances of this murder are unclear: Stanley says that he really loved his wife and that she has loved him. But then he mentions (I'm quoting from memory)

> If you really love someone, never come home early.

That would mean that he came home at an unusual time, saw something involving his wife, killed her, cut off her head and hid it.

But why has he killed her? The most obvious thing coming to mind is her infidelity - He comes home, finds his wife with a lover, and kills her. But there is no information anywhere about 3rd person anywhere and this wouldn't explain the mutilation either - Jefferson seems to be extremely calm and calculating, so such a "crime of passion" doesn't seem to be in his nature. Also, in the last episode, he mentions:

> When you find her head, you will understand why she had to die.

Is there any information about the circumstances of this crime?

Answer (score 2):

> But why has he killed her? The most obvious thing coming to mind is her infidelity

Given the articles out there, seems to be a no.

> Is there any information about the circumstances of this crime?

So far, several sources repeat the same idea, so they either read each other and wrote it up or it is the most likeliest scenario given the information present in the episodes shown.

> WHY DID JEFFERSON GRIEFF KILL HIS WIFE IN INSIDE MAN?
>
> Jefferson Grieff killed his wife over a misunderstanding regarding crimes committed by her father.
>
> The murder of Grieff’s wife is centered on her father and Grieff’s former father-in-law, Gordon
>
> Grieff remains level-headed throughout Inside Man *until he shares a scene with Gordon* and his demeanor completely shifts, with him becoming highly antagonistic and hostile towards Gordon, even going as far as calling him a “criminal,” despite the fact Grieff is the one in prison for murder.
>
> However, from Grieff’s comments and hints that Gordon has a small army of people working for him, we can work out that he is the boss of a criminal organization that has carried out its own string of terrible deeds.
>
> When he either tried to expose Gordon or back out from the organization, Gordon got to his daughter first and convinced her that Grieff was trying to bring him down or was behind a serious crime of his own.
>
> But in order to get his revenge against Gordon for his crimes, Grieff decapitated his wife and hid her head so that Gordon would never be able to bury her daughter whole.

> Grieff teases the possibility of revealing why he killed his wife to Watling, saying that he thinks Harry might understand him as they are both the same now.
>
> Harry is adamant that the pair are nothing alike but Grieff notes how Watling’s actions in trying to shield criminal activity led to the death of his own wife.
>
> This hints that *Grieff’s involvement in or attempts to stop Gordon’s criminal activity resulted in the death of his wife*

https://www.hitc.com/en-gb/2022/11/08/why-did-jefferson-grieff-kill-his-wife-inside-man/

> it seems like the reason why Jefferson murdered his wife has a lot to do with her own father, Jefferson’s father-in-law Gordon.
>
> all signs point to Gordon being a criminal and Jefferson finding out about a specific crime he committed that he was going to expose.
>
> Aware that his own son-in-law might soon reveal his criminality to the world, Gordon then went to his own daughter to paint Jefferson in a bad light. The couple eventually confronts each other and Jefferson ends up strangulating her.
>
> The reason behind the decapitation is also related to Gordon: Jefferson hid his wife's head so that Gordon wouldn't have a chance to ever bury his daughter whole.

https://www.womanandhome.com/life/news-entertainment/inside-man-why-did-grieff-kill-his-wife/

https://screenrant.com/inside-man-jefferson-grieff-murder-wife-reason/

https://screenrant.com/inside-man-ending-explained-in-detail/

..and it might be revealed later. Or not:

> while Inside Man tells a "self-contained story", he's leaving the door open for a potential follow-up.

https://www.radiotimes.com/tv/drama/inside-man-bbc-ending-explained/

https://www.radiotimes.com/tv/drama/inside-man-season-2-steven-moffat-exclusive-newsupdate/

> when quizzed on why he murdered his wife, Grieff said: "That's a story for another day."

> So it seems that, at least for now, that mystery remains unsolved.
>
> Moffat has previously said that, given that we don't know why Grieff killed his wife or where he disposed of her head, he couldn't rule out a return in a spin-off or a sequel.
>
> "The story will end in four episodes. It's done by the end of that. As to whether or not you could ever spin off anything or do any kind of sequel? I don't know at this moment," the Sherlock writer told RadioTimes.com. "It's not really up to me, and it's not up to the broadcasters – it's up to the audience really, isn't it?

Comment: Thats quite interesting! But I'm still wondering about Jefferson's comment about "coming home too early"

Comment: I do suspect he has added those things in, just so he knows he has another potential writing job in the future (for a sequel), if the other offers dry up...